# Sort CCK Node Reference list

Tags: drupal, cck

I have the following content types:

```
Lesson
Challenge
```

When creating a Lesson, there is a Node Reference list of Challenges.  I would like to be able to drag/drop sort the list while adding/editing a Lesson.

Answer (score -1):

Use relationships http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-relationships

Comment: I updated the main post, I didn't explain that it's when Adding/Editing a Lesson, not viewing.